# Import users / sent personal email

Tags: email, zoo-visitor, datagrab

Im basicly wondering if the following is possible and what addons i should use.

Im planning to develop a site with around 10.000 users, im planning to use Zoo Vistor and import the user by datagrab.

Each user can sign up for some kind of workshop. The user can get 3 kind of status (or group)
- Signed up
- Signed off
- Default status

If i import the user i want to sent all user an email with their logindetails(or a setup for their password / reset password), this email needs to be personalised(containign username and some member fields).

Other than that i should be able to email each group(combine EE communcation module with Zoo?)  a personalised mail containing a message  like "Hello User, you haven't signed up yet, please sign up here".

Can someone advise me by using what modules  / ee setup?